# Input start-time, end-time and date produce proper start-date-time and end-date-time

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application with C#, one of requirement functions is on a certain user interface (windows form) users input start-time, end-time and date.  Then the application will produce proper start-date-time and end-date-time to be saved back into database. Details/scenarios are listed below.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

### Example 1:

If
Input date: 03/15/2013
Input start-time: 11:45 PM
Input end-time: 1:10 AM
Then,
Output start-date-time: "03/15/2013 23:45:00"
Ouput end-date-time:  "03/16/2013 01:10:00"   // note: the output end-date-time is 1 day after the start-date-time

### Example 2:

If
Input date: 03/15/2013
Input start-time: 9:45 PM
Input end-time: 10:30 PM
Then,
Output start-date-time: "03/15/2013 21:45:00"
Ouput end-date-time:  "03/15/2013  22:30:00"  // note: start-date-time and end-date-time have the same date

### Example 3:

If
Input date: 10/25/2012
Input start-time: 6:10 AM
Input end-time: 8:15 PM 
Then,
Output start-date-time: "10/25/2012 06:10:00"
Ouput end-date-time:  "10/25/2012  20:15:00"  // note: start-date-time and end-date-time have the same date

### Example 4:

If
Input date: 07/12/2010
Input start-time: 6:10 AM
Input end-time: 4:25 AM 
Then,
Output start-date-time: "07/12/2010 06:10:00"
Ouput end-date-time:  "07/13/2010 04:25:00"  // note: the output end-date-time is 1 day after the start-date-time

Comment: What have you tried? The `DateTime` object not only gives you time, but also the date. Start and end times provide you a date from which you can easily compose your output.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string InputDate = "3/15/2013";
    string InputStartTime = "11:45 PM";
    string InputEndTime = "1:10 AM";
    DateTime StartTime, EndTime;
    StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(InputDate + " " + InputStartTime);
    EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(InputDate + " " + InputEndTime);
    if (EndTime < StartTime)
        EndTime.AddDays(1);
    string OutputStartTime = StartTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    string OutputEndTime = EndTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: +1. But please, replace `EndTime += new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)` with `EndTime.AddDays(1)`. And if you want a one-day `TimeSpan`, use `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("03/15/2013 11:45 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I leave it to you to work out the logic required to create the string that is passed as the first parameter to this function based on your business rules.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

- create start date `D1` by combining input date and input start time
- create end date `D2` by combining input date and input end time
- if `D2` is before `D1` then add 1 day to `D2`